# SAS: Huge file/many tasks: split file into smaller, or split up the tasks?

Tags: sas

I have high-frequency financial data (miliseconds), lots of columns, 137 mio observations/lines, total size 32Gb. I want to aggregate observations into 30seconds-bins using PROC TIMESERIES. My initial command involves quite a lot of variables/tasks.

```
proc timeseries data=DATA out= DATA_SEC30; 
id DATETIME interval=sec30 setmissing=missing align=beg start = '01jan1999.00:05'dt end = '01dec2014.00:00'dt; 
var TRADE BID ASK MID / accumulate=last;
var TIME / accumulate=last;
var OF VOL / accumulate=total;
var DATE / accumulate=N;
run;
```

If I run this code I get the following error-message:

> ERROR: Unable to allocate sufficient memory. At least 312070K bytes were requested. You must either increase the amount of memory available, or approach the problem differently.

My question is what is best way to split the problem?

A) Split file in smaller (non-overlapping) files based on eg. date, and then run above code on each sub-file, and put them together at end?
or

B) Split above code in steps steps, e.g. one for each VAR-statement, but run on full file?

The answer may be procedure-specific, and computer-specific (but I was hoping for a "general" answer). I use PROC TIMESERIES, and the computer is a server where SAS is allocated about 256Gb memory.

Answer (score 1):

First off, given your particular issue, I would encourage you to contact SAS tech support.  You pay a lot of money for SAS, and one thing you get is nearly real time support on issues like this - often from the developers of the proc themselves.  Once you move beyond the basic data step and simple procs like SUMMARY/MEANS, TABULATE, FREQ, etc., and move into the high memory intensity stuff like TIMESERIES, there are often proc-specific optimizations that you can do that only a few people are likely to know.

As to what approach is best at addressing issues like this in *general*, there is no one answer.  When it won't affect results, it is likely preferable to split observations rather than rerunning the proc for different variables.  This is because of I/O constraints; reading the same 32GB four times vs. reading 8GB four times, the latter is clearly better.  Of course, sometimes (say in a regression analysis) this would change the results, and thus is not preferable.

When it is possible, you can use BY statements to help as well. This avoids the necessity to actually split the dataset; instead you have some variable that defines a group, and run BY that ID, allowing you to run the proc with one single call, in one pass, but run the analysis effectively multiple times, and produce just one final output dataset.  This usually (but not always) avoids out of memory situations.  I don't know if PROC TIMESERIES would work with this, but I think it probably would in your case.

Here's an example, using [the second example from the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_timeseries_sect037.htm) of PROC TIMESERIES.  First I run it on the whole SASHELP.AIR dataset, then BY yeargroup (which is the year rounded to the nearest multiple of 5).  Notice how the SERIES datasets are identical; thus that part of the analysis worked fine.  But the SEASON datasets are *not* identical, since the BY group analysis meant you had separate sets of Seasons for each BY value.  You'd need to understand how PROC TIMESERIES is working with your data to understand if a BY group is going to affect things or not.

```
 proc timeseries data=sashelp.air
                   out=series
                   outtrend=trend
                   outseason=season print=seasons;
      id date interval=qtr accumulate=avg;
      var air;
   run;



data air;
  set sashelp.air;
  yeargroup = round(year(date),5);
run;

 proc timeseries data=work.air
                   out=series2
                   outtrend=trend
                   outseason=season print=seasons;
      by yeargroup;
      id date interval=qtr accumulate=avg;
      var air;
   run;

   proc compare base=series compare=series2;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a reasonable compromise between writing the smallest amount of code and resource efficiency, I would probably run proc timeseries multiple times using different data set options, e.g.

```
proc timeseries data=DATA(firstobs = 1 obs = 10000000)...
proc timeseries data=DATA(firstobs = 10000001 obs = 20000000)...
```

In your case it looks as though just splitting the processing over two runs would be sufficient. Using `obs` and `firstobs` like this avoids creating indexes or temporary datasets and also avoids reading the whole dataset twice, as SAS only has to seek the position of `firstobs` in the second run, i.e. without actually reading any of the prior observations.

Depending on the complexity of what you're doing with `proc timeseries` and whether anyone else needs to use lots of memory on your server, you may find that it's worthwhile to write an equivalent data step. This would give you one single output dataset from one pass and would consume far less memory (probably only a few hundred KB), but could potentially be much more work to write and maintain.

Comment: Thanks. Observation num 1000001 may be in middle of a 30sec interval. Could I use WHERE-statements instead, using dates?

Comment: If this is a concern, you can write a trial data step that starts from obs. 1000001 and continues reading records until it finds the end of the 30 second period. Using where clauses / statements would take at least twice as long, as that would involve multiple reads of your whole dataset to see which records match. If your dataset is indexed on the time variable it might not be quite so bad, but not by much.